# How to load template a without mentioning its name in the #[Template] annotation in Symfony 6.2+?

Tags: symfony, twig

Using the no longer maintained `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` there used to be a `@Template` annotation that allowed to load a template without explicitlely mentioning its name in annotations:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin")
 * @Template()
 */
public function index(Request $request, DatagridFactory $datagridFactory)
{ ... }
```

https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/view.html

as `@Template()` was empty, Symfony would automatically load `admin/index.html.twig`

Now I have this action defined in `AdminController.php`

```
#[Route('/admin', name: 'admin_login')]
#[Template()]
public function index(Request $request)
{ ... }
```

But I'm receiving a construct error related to the template attribute saying that it must have parameter and I have to write `#[Template('admin/index.html.twig')]` to make it work.

Is there a way to make the `#[Template]` attribute behave in the same way as the older `@Template` annotation?

I did not find any info in official documentations - https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/templates.html

Comment: Well it's saying you need to write the template path, and the documentation says the same "Another option is to use the #[Template()] attribute on the controller method to define the template to render" So why don't you just do `#[Template('admin/index.html.twig')]`

Comment: My overall question here is how to automate it, and do not mention it !! cause i used to do so with old symfony versions

Comment: I would not recommend it as I feel it's not worth the effort, but you could create your own attribute that handle the rendering with event onKernelView to render a page, you should just look at how it's currently working and update the behavior by doing what you want. But again, you are gonna overcomplicate something that has been changed for a purpose: make it simpler and more explicit.

Comment: As there is no official way i will juts get mention always desired template, thanks for comments !